# Counting how many times a loop runs

Tags: java

If we have a loop like this

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i+=2) 
{
    total+=1;
}
```

I assume there is one instruction in the header, and it executes one instruction in the body so the total number of instruction is (n-0)/2*1+1 (last condition). Is it the right way to do it? How would you count it?

Also, how about this?

```
for(int i=1; i<n; i*=2)
{
    total+=1;
}
```

If n = 20, i goes like 1,2,4,8,16, and I'm not sure how to calculate it

Comment: First one: n/2
Second one: log2(n)

Comment: The first one is actualy (n+1)/2.

Comment: @JasonC I think it's n instead of n+1, because it doesn't include n.

Comment: @B.A. No, it's most certainly (n+1)/2. The second is log2(n-1)+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write them out on paper and look for a pattern. For your first example:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i+=2) 

n  i's      total
0  []       0
1  [0]      1 
2  [0]      1
3  [0,2]    2
4  [0,2]    2
5  [0,2,4]  3
6  [0,2,4]  3
   and so on..
```

That is *floor((n+1)/2)* (or integer division).

The second one; we can see it's going to be related to log2 just by examination, so let's compare the counts with log2(n) to see if we can find a pattern:

```
for(int i=1; i<n; i*=2)

n   i's        total   log2(n)
1   []            0     ---
2   [1]           1     1
3   [1,2]         2     1.58
4   [1,2]         2     2
5   [1,2,4]       3     2.32
6   [1,2,4]       3     2.58
7   [1,2,4]       3     2.81
8   [1,2,4]       3     3
9   [1,2,4,8]     4     3.17
10  [1,2,4,8]     4     3.32
11  [1,2,4,8]     4     3.46
12  [1,2,4,8]     4     3.58
13  [1,2,4,8]     4     3.70
14  [1,2,4,8]     4     3.81
15  [1,2,4,8]     4     3.91
16  [1,2,4,8]     4     4
17  [1,2,4,8,16]  5     4.09
```

Looking at this and thinking about it for a moment we can see it is *floor(1+log2(n-1))*, with special cases for n=0 (total=0) and n=1 (total=0).

The thought process in that last one is: we have to "shift" the *log2* column down one to make it line up with the *total* column (hence *log2(n-1)*), and we have to add 1 to it to make the values match.